# Efficient way to do conditional checks on Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, if-statement, numpy

I am trying to perform some conditional checks on numpy arrays and my code right now is not very pythonic. Can someone suggest more efficient ways to write the code below ?

1. h is a 2D numpy array of floats with dimension nrows*ncols
2. ibound is a 2D numpy array of ints with dimension nrows*ncols
3. L1TopOld is a 2D numpy array of floats with dimension nrows*ncols

> ```
> eps = 1.0e-04
> #Fill in gaps in the surfaces#####################################
> for i in range(nrows):
>   for j in range(ncols):
>       if (ibound[i,j] == 1 and fabs(h[i,j]-nodata) <= eps):
>           h[i,j] = L1TopOld[i,j]
> ```

Comment: For clarification, ibound can have values other than 0 and 1. I tested DMS's and Taha's suggestions and both worked for me. I like DSM's suggestion slightly better because it gave me an if/then type option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).  First, let's make some toy data (BTW, it helps if you do this part of it yourself):

```
>>> h = np.random.random((3,4))
>>> nodata = 10
>>> h.flat[[2,3,4,7,8,9]] = 10
>>> ibound = np.random.randint(0,2,(3,4))
>>> L1TopOld = np.ones((3,4))*5
>>> h
array([[  0.1382408 ,   0.7718657 ,  10.        ,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,   0.5595833 ,   0.83703255,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,  10.        ,   0.79473842,   0.91882331]])
>>> ibound
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> L1TopOld
array([[ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.]])
>>> eps = 0.01
```

Now we can decide which ones we want to patch:

```
>>> ibound & (abs(h-nodata) <= eps)
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])
```

and use this to tell `np.where` where we want to switch:

```
>>> np.where(ibound & (abs(h - nodata) <= eps), L1TopOld, h)
array([[  0.1382408 ,   0.7718657 ,   5.        ,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,   0.5595833 ,   0.83703255,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,   5.        ,   0.79473842,   0.91882331]])
```

As pointed out in the comments, this assumes that `ibound` is a mask consisting only of 0 and 1.  If you really only want to change the cases where `ibound == 1` (and not 2, for example), that's easy too:

```
>>> np.where((ibound == 1) & (abs(h - nodata) <= eps), L1TopOld, h)
array([[  0.1382408 ,   0.7718657 ,   5.        ,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,   0.5595833 ,   0.83703255,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,   5.        ,   0.79473842,   0.91882331]])
```

(which gives the same answer here because 0 and 1 were the only numbers in `ibound`.)

Comment: Will this work if ```ibound``` contains ints other than zero and one?

Comment: @wwii: you're right, I assumed it was a 0/1 mask.  If not, you'd have to replace `ibound &` with `(ibound == 1) &`.

Comment: I have seen ```numpy.where()``` used often in answers but don't understand when it should be used instead of conditionally modifying the original array like ```h[mask] = L1TopOld[mask]``` with boolean indexing.  Any tips/ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the original array:

```
import numpy as np
eps = .01
nodata = 10
h = np.array([[0.1382408, 0.7718657, 10. , 10. ],
              [ 10. , 0.5595833, 0.83703255, 10. ],
              [ 10. , 10. , 0.79473842, 0.91882331]])
h.flat[[2,3,4,7,8,9]] = 10
ibound = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1]])
L1TopOld = np.array([[ 5., 5., 5., 5.],
                     [ 5., 5., 5., 5.],
                     [ 5., 5., 5., 5.]])
```

Create a logical mask with your condition:

```
mask = (ibound == 1) & (abs(h - nodata) <= eps)
```

Modify the array using boolean indexing

```
h[mask] = L1TopOld[mask]
print h

[[  0.1382408    0.7718657    5.          10.        ]
 [ 10.           0.5595833    0.83703255  10.        ]
 [ 10.           5.           0.79473842   0.91882331]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to proceed the vectorial way:

```
cond = (ibound == 1) & (np.fabs(h - nodata) <= eps)
h[cond] = L1TopOld[cond]
```

Let's see an example (I am using the one proposed in the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24063502/revisions)):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> h = np.random.random((3, 4))
>>> nodata = 10
>>> h.flat[[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]] = nodata
>>> ibound = np.random.randint(0, 2, (3, 4))
>>> L1TopOld = np.ones((3, 4)) * 5
>>> eps = 0.01

>>> ibound
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> L1TopOld
array([[ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.],
       [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.]])
>>> h
array([[  0.89332453,   0.71094897,  10.        ,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,   0.47419211,   0.50206745,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,  10.        ,   0.71388832,   0.84379527]])

>>> cond = (ibound == 1) & (np.fabs(h - nodata) <= eps)
>>> cond
array([[False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> h[cond] = L1TopOld[cond]
>>> h
array([[  0.89332453,   0.71094897,   5.        ,  10.        ],
       [ 10.        ,   0.47419211,   0.50206745,   5.        ],
       [  5.        ,   5.        ,   0.71388832,   0.84379527]])
```

Yours